# Can one change only the lower/upper bound in R histograms (hist) with arguments xlim and ylim?

Tags: r, histogram

I would like to know if it's possible to only change one "limit" (either lower or upper) when plotting histograms in R using the `hist` functions with argument `xlim` and `ylim`. For instance, I would only like to change the lowest horizontal axis value, while leaving the upper one at its default choice. Conceptually, I'd like to do sth along the lines of `hist(x, xlim=c(-5,NA))` where NA would mean "leave default unchanged". Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can compute the default value for `ylim`, and change it, as follows:

```
x <- rnorm(100)
h <- hist(x, plot = FALSE)  # Data that would be plotted
ylim <- range( h$counts )   # Default values
ylim[1] <- -5               # Change only one value
plot( h, ylim = ylim )      # or: hist( x, ylim = ylim )
```

Comment: Thank you - this is very helpful. And to make it work for xlim, one can use h$breaks.